# Can you zoom the windowbuilder in order to see more of your design?

Tags: eclipse, resize, zooming, fullscreen, windowbuilder

I am working a project on windowbuilder of eclipse. My frame is fullscreen so it does not fit in the design page of WB.

The same problem also happens with JScrollPanes, in the design-view of Windowbuilder you can see the scrollbars, but you cant use them.

Is there anyway to zoom out WB so that I can have overall view of my window?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot zoom in/out in window builder but you can use the editor scroll bars to view to specific parts of your large window area, you can also right click and select "preview" to see the actual application window. If you cannot see the scroll bars in the window builder editor and you are using a mac, use an external mouse and they will show up. Also add this to your eclipse.ini file -Dswt.enable.themedScrollBar=false

Hope that helps - Duncan Krebs